# Varnish has no SSL support; then what to use?

Tags: commerce, proxies, ssl

As the developer of Varnish, Poul Henning, wrote back in 2011 on https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/phk/ssl.html and again this year on https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/phk/ssl_again.html Varnish has and will have no SSL support.

If this is true for Apache servers (note  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-varnish-cache-4-0-with-ssl-termination-on-ubuntu-14-04 has instructions on how to configure both on Nginx), then I wonder what are Varnish alternatives for Drupal sites that need to be running through HTTPS (like, for example, Drupal Commerce sites)?

Answer (score 2):

Content delivery platforms like [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) and [Fastly](https://www.fastly.com/) offer a wide range of SSL/TLS options. The question is, what are you trying to accomplish? Note that Varnish really won't do you any good for high transaction-volume sites because you're dealing with authenticated traffic. However, services like the ones listed above can be useful for delivering assets or for serving anonymous traffic.

Comment: Just wanted to say that Drupal 8 can cache authenticated users [Drupal 8's Dynamic Page Cache](http://wimleers.com/article/drupal-8-dynamic-page-cache) I'm sure you Commerce Guys already knew this, so this is just for the readers =)

Comment: Good point! Drupal 8 fixes quite a bit in that arena!

Comment: So how do D7 Commerce sites deal with the authenticated user issue? By scaling their server horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends to what you want to do. 
Look at this tutorial here
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-varnish-cache-4-0-with-ssl-termination-on-ubuntu-14-04

and here
http://blog.ajnicholls.com/varnish-apache-and-https/